# How to disable the Mac OS X Dashboard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, operating-systems

I'm using Mac OS 10.6.7 on a low memory MacBook, so I would like to kill the Dashboard and not have it running at login. Tried this

```
    defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -boolean YES
```

...but couldn't make it work.

Comment: That last sentence provides absolutely no information, since you fail to mention *which* commands didn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel, I've added the command now.

Comment: Have you logged out and back in since entering the command?

Comment: @DanielBeck Or reopened Dock.

Comment: Yes, I've logged out and back. Didn't work :(

Comment: Either logging out and back in or relaunching Dock worked for me on 10.6.7. And `defaults` doesn't care about the capitalization of the bundle identifier (`com.apple.dashboard` vs `com.apple.Dashboard`).

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool true && killall Dock
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, something else is going on. It didn't work for me.

Comment: @villares To clarify, Dashboard is still running although you set this command?

Comment: Still works with 10.8.

Comment: I typed `sudo` in front of it, just in case.

Comment: @bobobobo `defaults` manages *user defaults*, or, in other words, preferences. Some of them are hidden, but they're almost exclusively user account specific.